# Java Unicode вывод

Tags: java, unicode

Есть 16 ричное представление числа,как с помощью `System.out.println('\uXXXX');` вывести символы,если эти самые `XXXX` постоянно меняются?или если зайти с другой стороны,пусть `ХХХХ` поступает как результат работы определенной функции,как можно поступить?

Comment: в чем у вас храниться это представление? вы хотите вывести без \u?

Comment: @Виктор в String,ну без \u я вряд ли получу символ из таблицы Unicode,поэтому с ним

Comment: тогда не понятно в чем проблема? Если в String положить "\u0B08", то на выходе получим "ଈ"

Comment: @Виктор проблема в том что у меня в String есть только 0B08,без \u,в этом и вся загвоздка,а разделить \u без ХХХХ не получится

Comment: В строке код одного символа? Если нескольких то они склеены или разделены?

Comment: @Виктор одного символа,т.е String = E7C7,к примеру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `Integer` есть метода [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

С его помощью можно перевести строку в число, если знаешь систему счисления.

```
String number = "E7C7";
char E7C7 = (char)Integer.parseInt(number, 16);
System.out.println(E7C7);
```

На экран будет выведено ``

Comment: огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "\uXXXX";
    char s1 = s.toCharArray()[0];
```